# Visual Studio 2010 Database Builds Drop If Exists

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build-automation, database-project

Is there any way i can change the "Alter" statements for tables and procs to "Drop if exists" when the build spits out the scripts??
Using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. TFS 2010.

Comment: It's hard for me to tell from your question what tool you using to generate the scripts.  I answered the question but I'm not sure if the scripts mentioned are the ones used by VS.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code you are referring to is generated from a template.

Look here...

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\Templates\Database Project Items

and the modify these two files.

- New Table Script.sql
- New Stored Procedure Script.sql

Comment: hmm perhaps but I think that is probably the template used when creating scripts/tables in a database project, not used by the schema comparer, will look though.

Comment: sounds promising. will let you know and mark this as an answer if that works.

Answer (score 0):

After the procedure has been created for the first time what you will see is the code the tool gets/reads from the database, no longer an script that you could edit; of course you could copy/paste whatever it shows you into a text editor and save it as an SQL file (.sql extension).

If you try this sample code

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'usp_test_proc')
    BEGIN
        DROP  Procedure  usp_test_proc
    END
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.usp_test_proc
    /*
    (
    @parameter1 int = 5,
    @parameter2 datatype OUTPUT
    )
    */
AS
    /* SET NOCOUNT ON */
    select name, comment from test_table
    RETURN
```

you will get this message:

"Unable to save object because the statement type is not supported. It must begin with CREATE or ALTER."

I suggest you create your own SQL procedure files and add the exists statment at the top, for example:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'usp_test_proc')
    BEGIN
        DROP  Procedure  usp_test_proc
    END
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_test_proc
    /*
    (
    @parameter1 int = 5,
    @parameter2 datatype OUTPUT
    )
    */
AS
    /* SET NOCOUNT ON */
    select name, comment from test_table
    RETURN
```

That way you can edit/change your SQL code file at your convenience then just recreate the procedure connecting to your database by opening a new query connection through the Visual Studio menu 'Data/Transact-SQL Editor/New Query Connection', opening the SQL file and clicking on the Execute SQL toolbar button (green arrow).

Comment: I suggest using CREATE-ALTER, rather than DROP-CREATE, to avoid losing permissions that may have been applied to the stored proc when you drop and recreate it.  With CREATE-ALTER the initial check is IF NOT EXISTS then create a simple dummy proc.  Then the main section of the script is ALTER PROC.  I've given example code here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15911851/216440